# Creating more than one JADE agent using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, agents-jade

Does anyone who is familiar with JADE knows how to create more than one jade agents at once using eclipse and send messages within them? If you are ok, if you give your email address i may be able to contact you whenever i get any doubt on JADE. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can run any number of agents running jade from cmd, code or using eclipse project settings.
Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually works. I tried.

```
String name = "Alice" ;
AID alice = new AID( name, AID.ISLOCALNAME );

AgentContainer c = getContainerController();

        try {
            AgentController a = c.createNewAgent(name,"com.sender.Receiver", null);
            a.start();
            System.out.println(alice.getLocalName() + " Created");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```